# recursively chmod

Tags: command-line, find, chmod, xargs

I was trying to `chmod` folders and files with:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

But I was wondering:

1. How to do it in one line using `find` and excluding the directories `.` and `..`
2. Which method is better, `find -exec` or `xargs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sherlock got (1), for (2) `xargs` is generally preferable as it allows for more reasonable syntax and less shell invocation overhead. Be aware of the `-print0` and `-0` options to find and xargs respectively as paths with spaces and special characters can gum up the works.

For a one-time run, the difference really shouldn't matter unless you are chmodding a huge tree. If you do this often enough to formalize into a script, I'd use xargs.

Answer (score 10):

Is using `find` or `xargs` mandatory?

If not, you can use:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX *
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the named arguments to chmod:

```
 chmod u=rwX,go=rX {}
```

The capital `X` is the key part here which changes the permission to executable only if it is a directory. See [the manual page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + -or -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

---

`find ... -exec ... +` is like `find ... -exec ... \;` except that the command is executed only once per large set of matching files.

Once upon a time, `find OPTIONS... -exec COMMAND... \;` had to act on one file at a time. So `xargs` was invented to group actions for efficiency. But `xargs` introduced its own share of trouble: it expects input that is quoted in a way that `find` cannot produce. So `find OPTIONS... | xargs COMMAND...` is no good unless you know that your file names do not contain any of `'"\` or whitespace.

Then GNU invented `find OPTIONS... -print0 | xargs -0 COMMAND...`, which allows any character to appear in a file name. But it took a long time for anyone else to adopt it, and in the meantime Sun (I think) invented `find OPTIONS... -exec COMMAND... +`, which does the same grouping job as `xargs`, without the added complications (longer command line, limit to one per `find` command). Now `find ... -exec ... +` is standard (it's in [Single Unix v3](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)), and more widely available than `xargs -0`. Unless you have to maintain compatibility with an old Linux system, just forget about `xargs`.